# Mixed Effects Analysis in MATLAB

Tags: mixed-model, matlab

I am new to Mixed Effects analysis, so please forgive my ignorance. I would like to determine if there is any significance between the means of two successive time points in an imaging ROI study. Each ROI contains 2500 voxels and there are 6 time points (thus, 6 mean values, one for each time point). Currently, I set up the analysis as follows:

```
tbl = table(Voxels, Mean, Time, 'VariableNames', {'Voxels','Mean','Time'});
```

Voxels, Mean, and Time are 15000 x 1 vectors as follows:

```
Voxels Mean Time
   2   3.4   1
   3   3.4   1
   .    .    .
   23   19   2
   16   19   2
   .    .    .
   19   13   6
   6    13   6
```

How do I go about setting up the model equation? I was thinking,

```
fitlme(tbl, 'Mean ~ Voxels + (1 | Time)  + (Voxels-1 | Time)' );
```

Answer (score 1):

If your interest lies in comparing the mean outcome scores over time, it sounds like time should be adjusted in the model as a fixed effect, i.e. `Mean ~ time`. To specify a random intercept for voxel, accounting for some of the intracluster variability, you may use a term like `(1 | voxel)` in the formula. This gives you something very similar to the repeated measures ANOVA.